# my /index.html is redirecting to /[object Object]

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn some javascript, and have been writing my code as .js files and importing them to an index.html page.

Before all my errors were fixed, the page and canvas loaded properly. Now the page redirects before firebug can check for anything. And just displays the error "cannot find the file at [object Object]".

the index.html code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Life</title>
    <script src='js/Map.js'></script>
    <script src='js/Game.js'></script>
    <script src='js/Animal.js'></script>
    <script src='js/Block.js'></script>
    <script src='js/Food.js'></script>
    <script src='js/Shapes.js'></script>
    <script src='js/Menu.js'></script>
    <style>
        #screen {
            display:block; 
            margin:0 auto; 
            background-color:#000; 
        }
        .fpsmeter {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .fpsmeter p {
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='screen' width='1200' height='500'></canvas>
    <div id="fpscontainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not really sure where to look to find the solution to the problem.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23801920/Html5/life/index.html

Links to js files.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23801920/Html5/life/js/Animal.js

"                                                         "Block.js

"                                                         "Food.js

"                                                         "Game.js

"                                                         "Map.js

"                                                         "Menu.js

"                                                         "Shapes.js

I know there are probably a lot of other problems, but I'd just like help with this problem.

I believe ChiChou answered my question, but I have a bit of bug checking to do before I know for sure!

Comment: You will need to provide your javascript code as well, as its obvious that the redirect is triggered through it.

Comment: its some thing to do with the js files..plz post js file code

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't think of a good way to share that much code on here. I added dropbox links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have missed `new` operator somewhere.

Check out the following code:

```
Animal = function (location, age, direction, dna, parentA, parentB){
//this = Block('animal');
this.type = 'animal';
this.age = age;
this.location = location;
         ^^^^^^^^
```

You should use `var animal = new Animal()` to create a new instance of Animal. If you directly call function `Animal()`, `this` inside the function will be a reference to `window`. Assigning value to `window.location` will make a redirection.

So you actually call something like:

```
window.location = location.toString();
```

Mofidy `this.location` to `this._location` will temporary solve this, but for a fundamental solution, you should find out where you call the function in a wrong way.